# Do Ethereum tokens have symbol name?

Tags: tokens, ether

I am not familiar with Ethereum contract development. I wonder if Ethereum tokens ( like ERC20, ERC1155 or ERC721) have symbol name or not.
On EOSIO the asset is a structure composed of amount and symbol.

Comment: ERC20 has both name and symbol. Why not simply read the spec?

Comment: Probably I opened wrong spec. Now I am reading [this](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md).  what does this mean? `OPTIONAL - This method can be used to improve usability, but interfaces and other contracts MUST NOT expect these values to be present.` What about ERC721 tokens? Also, as I understand, ERC1155 don't have symbol names. Am I right.